# Overlay of icon on bottom

Tags: html, css

Following is my fiddle on which I am trying to put an overlay of Icon just like the following image kindly let me know how can i do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/czvRa/

[image]

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 5px; background-color: rgb(62, 160, 85); color: white; display: inline-block; padding: 8px;">
Inbox<br>
<span style="line-height: 25px;">0</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify, it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/czvRa/2/

Comment: @Rich oops sorry didnot mention `overlay of Icon`

Comment: @VikasGhodke yup just like this but I am using Font for Icon, so what would be thee css in that case?

Comment: are u using font awesome

Comment: @PremAnand yup I am using http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[See the Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/czvRa/4/)**

Here i am using glyphicon, but you can use any icons you want.

HTML

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 5px; background-color: rgb(62, 160, 85); color: white; display: inline-block; padding: 8px;">
Inbox<br>
<span style="line-height: 25px;">0</span>
<span class="someclass glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
.someclass {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 5px; background-color: rgb(62, 160, 85); color: white; display: inline-block; padding: 8px;">
Inbox<br>
<span style="line-height: 25px;">0</span>
<i class="icon-sun"></i>
</div>
```

You can increase or reduce the size of icons using icon-large, icon-2x, icon-3x, icon-4x classes

And Little CSS work is needed